# Why can't I get @font-face to work on custom fonts for wordpress?

Tags: html, css, wordpress, fonts

I'm using wordpress and find it impossible to get my custom fonts to work on my site. I've looked through several threads with the same problem and none of the solutions worked or I applied them wrong. I use a free theme that I'm modifying as I go along. I'm editing the style.css sheet and can't figure out what I'm doing wrong. Some fonts work that can be found on my computer (and some don't, even if they can be found on my PC), so there seems to be something really weird going on. None of the @font-face things work on other devices.

I used font squirrel to make a set of webfonts and uploaded them to my server, under the theme in a separate font folder. The files should be accessible as the permissions are granted to user, group, world for read and execute. I also now tried using the font squirrel provided code added with complete addresses to implement the fonts. Nothing happens.

Now this is my first day into coding so it might be I'm not seeing what I'm doing wrong here. I inserted this new code after the HEADING-headline (I'm not sure if the positioning in the sheet makes a difference or is it just for the user for organizational purposes, but I've tried several) in the style file and this is a strip as is on the file:

```
.blog-title {
    font-family: "daniel_blackregular";
    font-size: 2.25em;
    text-align: center;
}

@font-face {
    font-family: 'daniel_blackregular';
    src: url('/public_html/wp-content/themes/baskerville/Fonts/danielbk.eot');
    src: url('/public_html/wp-content/themes/baskerville/Fonts/danielbk.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
         url('/public_html/wp-content/themes/baskerville/Fonts/danielbk.woff2') format('woff2'),
         url('/public_html/wp-content/themes/baskerville/Fonts/danielbk.woff') format('woff'),
         url('danielbk.ttf') format('truetype');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
}
```

Right now I'm thinking what if I'm addressing the font incorrectly, but I've tried everything there too. Please help.

Comment: Would you mind posting the link to your staging site as well?

Comment: I don't have a separate staging site but this is the site: http://controlledrandomness.com/

Answer (score 0):

To fix your issue you need to do a few things.

1. Move your @font-face to the top of your css file.
2. Update the url path in your @font-face call. Right now they are returning a 404 with the urls of:

---

```
@font-face {
font-family: 'daniel_blackregular';
src: url('/fonts/danielbk.eot');
src: url('/fonts/danielbk.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
     url('/fonts/danielbk.woff2') format('woff2'),
     url('/fonts/danielbk.woff') format('woff'),
     url('/fonts/danielbk.ttf') format('truetype');
font-weight: normal;
font-style: normal;
}
```

---

Remember the urls are relative to where the call is coming from. In this case it's gettning called from your css.

When I updated the paths in the css to: src: url('/public_html/wp-content/themes/baskerville/Fonts/danielbk.eot'); the font worked.

Comment: Hmm... But I had those urls in the first place? I moved the font-face in the beginning with nothing above it and changed the urls, but it's still not working. :/ But isn't the css file in the theme folder?

Comment: actually on the live site i removed the / before fonts and the font worked.

Comment: Damn. It's alive! :D Thank you so much! There's so much more to learn, but this has helped me understand coding a lot.

Comment: Oh awesome! Good job

Comment: And if you don't mind, how do you test that on the live site?

Comment: Just in chrome with their dev tools